# After reinstallatio of ubuntu all photos deleted. Do you know any apps or any command lines where i can restore them;;

Tags: data-recovery, photo

Hallo to everyone how are you;; I travelled to 6 countries and i had thousands of photos inside. For xy reason because i couldn't open the laptop ( it was constantly crashing) i decided to delete everything and reinstall ubuntu. Do you know any program or any useful information where i can type through command line and restore the photos;;; I have to get them back.

Comment: Chances are that by reinstalling the OS, you made it impossible to recover the photos.

Comment: You can look at [the posts tagged data-recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery?tab=Votes). But honestly, if you want to recover them, you really may need a professional data recovery company. Also, _anything_ you do on your computer, including turning it on, decreases the chances that you can recover something. So stop using that machine right away!

Comment: Why did you delete something that you wanted to keep? You should have thought about saving your photos before you deleted everything. After booting from Ubuntu install media, you should have not installed Ubuntu, but using the live session ("try Ubuntu") you should have copied your photos for example to external disk. Now you have deleted everything, so to recover them seek help of a professional data recovery service, as said in previous comment. But even in that case there's no guarantee they will be able to recover the data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

It will be extremely difficult to recover material if you reinstalled and reformatted the disk. File structures are entirely overwritten, and some of the actual data also will be overwritten by the newly installed files.

The tools "testdisk" and "photorec" offer a possibility to resurrect binary blobs of data still existing on a disk to usable files, but do not hold your breath: at best, you will recover thousands of files with random names. You will need to sift through these to see if 1) they still can be opened and 2) what they represent.

There are professional services for recovering data, but these are extremely expensive.

Ultimately, this example again points to the extreme importance of maintaining up-to-date spare copies of valuable user data.